# JQuery UI draggable clone to map

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, grid, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm making some kind of grid map editor, more as an experiment to learn by now and have encounter some problem.

Situation:

- I have a 20x20 grid of 10px x 10px div's (could be anything else) with black background, all droppable.
- I have two divs outside that grid, one gray and one green, draggable, to fill the grid as I want cloning them.

When I drag one of those two special divs and drop in a droppable grid div, let's call it "drop1", this drop1 turns into the color i want, let's say green, but the original green becomes undraggable so I can't use it to "fill" another droppable div.

This is my JS:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        revert: "invalid" ,
        helper: function(){
            $copy = $(this).clone();
            return $copy;},
        appendTo: 'body',
        scroll: false
    });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
        hoverClass: "droppableHover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .removeClass( "droppable" )
                .addClass( function(){
                    if ($ui.hasClass('graycell'))
                        return 'graycell';
                    else return 'greencell';
                })
                .addClass( "draggable" )
        }
    });
});
```

And this is some of the HTML:

```
                    <div class="graycell draggable" id="gray"></div>
                    <div class="greencell draggable" id="green"></div> 

<div title="(0,0)" class="cellborder droppable" id="0_0"></div>
<div title="(0,1)" class="cellborder droppable" id="0_1"></div>
<div title="(0,2)" class="cellborder droppable" id="0_2"></div>
<div title="(0,3)" class="cellborder droppable" id="0_3"></div>
<div title="(0,4)" class="cellborder droppable" id="0_4"></div>
<div title="(0,16)" class="cellborder droppable" id="0_16"></div>
```

I'm not sure I have explained myself very well, so sorry and ask for clarifications if you need them.

**EDIT:**

I've found that when I don't use a function in the .addClass() method of the droppable element (like using .addClass('gray') directly), this works as I want, but when I add the function (as in the code shown above) to select from two classes, It doesn't work, like It's not "cloning" the div actually.